# CSS layout issues in Safari 7

Tags: html, css, safari, media-queries

If I repeatedly shrink and expand the window past an @media breakpoint in Safari 7, list items displayed as table cells are displayed on two, then three, then four or more lines. One would expect them to snap back to just being one line. What's going on here?

Example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .nav > li {
        display: table-cell;
        width: 1%;
      }
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="nav">
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>       
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Screenshots at https://i.stack.imgur.com/Md8dh.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: table;` to the `<ul>` element. Safari does not like it when you have cells that are not nested in a table, and besides, it does make more sense that way (at least to me).

You could also set the `<ul>` to `display: inline;` for the same effect (it makes the element work in a *[block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting)*), but you might aswell go for the table. :-)

You may also want to consider wrapping the cells in rows.

*[Here a link to the docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#table-display)* on the display table property.

Comment: That was exactly it. Thanks! (It does makes sense; I guess I just figured Safari would infer a table like it infers a row - apparently not!)